# How convert sjplot sjt.corr() to dataframe in R

Tags: r, knitr, sjplot

my intention is to know how I can extract or convert to data.frame or any other, well my goal is to try to use it in knitr with latex.

```r
library(foreign)
library(sjPlot)
tb = read.spss(file = "dates.sav",use.value.labels = T,to.data.frame = T)
c = sjt.corr(tb[c(1,3,5)],show.p = T,p.numeric = T)
c # view in html
```

when trying to use knitr with latex a tremendous html code comes out and not the table seen in R.

```latex
<<echo=FALSE>>
c = sjt.corr(tb[c(1,3,5)],show.p = T,p.numeric = T)
c % show code html
```

Comment: `sjt.corr()` - or in general, the tablr-functions in package sjPlot, only produce HTML-tables, which can be easily integrated in knitr-HTML documents, or copy-pasted to Word, but unfortunately, they don't work well with Latex-output.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, Is there a similar library that generates results **similar to SPSS**? concerning variable correlation